# Qmail Installation CentosI386

Tags: email

I was trying to install qmailtoster in my centos server, i did all of the following not for once but repetitively as i got error and continued but i felt i need some help.

i did follow all the steps of this wiki documentation.

http://wiki.qmailtoaster.com/index.php/CentOS_5_QmailToaster_Install#Begin_Install

followed all procedure when i came in a point to install i always got this error.

```
cnt50-install-script.sh: line 80: rpmbuild: command not found 
error: File not found by glob: /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/i386/daemontools-toaster*.rpm
Installing ucspi-tcp-toaster . . .
Shall we continue? (yes, skip, quit) [y]/s/q:
cnt50-install-script.sh.4: line 90: rpmbuild: command not found
error: File not found by glob: /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/i386/ucspi-tcp-toaster*.rpm
Installing vpopmail-toaster . . .
Shall we continue? (yes, skip, quit) [y]/s/q:
```

any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where's `rpmbuild`?

`whereis rpmbuild` at the command line will tel you whether or not it's installed.  From there we can all progress.

Comment: when i come to this point
#sh cnt50-install-script.sh

i get following error
cnt50-install-script.sh: line 80: rpmbuild: command n ot found
error: File not found by glob: /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/i 386/courier-imap-toaster*.rpm
Installing ucspi-tcp-toaster . . .
Shall we continue? (yes, skip, quit) [y]/s/q:

and so on for every installation.